# CSV file Import

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I have a CSV file. It contains a String value in a column which is 'SK1202' when I read CSV the string is changing to '1202.0000' and subsequent values under that column is becoming Empty String. I tried with 'sk1202' it worked fine. Is there any meaning for 'SK' in CSV. I thought may be Alphanumeric combination is failing while reading, but all other Alphanumeric strings I read.

```
// Get the CSV file records 
importFile = 'sample.csv';
queryService = new Query();
queryService.setDataSource(csv_dsn);
queryService.setName("GetData");
queryService.setSql("SELECT * FROM #importFile#");
GetData = queryService.execute().getResult();
```

CSV contains

ID,Group
68247132,SK1202
68247133,BURGER124

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: Please include enough code to fully replicate your issue. How do you expect us to help you with such little information?

Comment: I added code and the file contents of CSV.

Comment: What are you looking at when you see the new value?

Comment: I want to use 'Group' column value.

Comment: (Edit) *RE: the file contents of CSV* Where are the commas? :) Can you post a snippet of the actual file (and code format that block)? *RE: the string is changing to '1202.0000'* What value is returned for "ID"?

Comment: Hi Leigh, I copied contents so was not showing commas. Can you try reading this contents using ODBC socket.

Comment: It worked fine. Though you are missing the third column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Bug or Something with ODBC Socket for Microsoft Text Driver(*.txt,*.csv) it converts String starting with 'SK' like 'SK1202' to '1202.0000' .
So I read CSV through 'cffile' took data on comma delimiters and new line. Then got data as an Array, updated Query Object which I got from Selecting CSV file through ODBC socket.

Corrected whole Query objected which I got from reading through ODBC socket.

Comment: I doubt the "SK" is the issue. Something else is causing the behavior. I was not able to reproduce it with the single line alone. Sounds like it could be a malformed file, but it is hard to say without the actual csv. Side note - what are you doing with the CSV content? Importing it into a db table? If so, database tools offer much better import options ie BULK INSERT, LOAD DATA, etc...

Comment: I am just reading and saving to Databse. While reading 'SK' is converting it to Decimal Numbers. I have saved CSV through Google Docs, try with having 'SK' followed by numbers then read through ODBC Socket and Dump the result. You will get to know the issue.

Comment: *I am just reading and saving to Databse.* Then why not just import it directly into the db and skip the extra hoops?  Honestly I always use JDBC, so I do not have ODBC services installed. However, they just use  an odbc dsn on the o/s. I created a system dsn and it returned "SK1202 68247133"  just fine. So again, I do not think the "SK" is the problem, not directly anyway. If you must use odbc, always use a [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file. Otherwise, the driver will "guess" the data types of the file columns.

Comment: The Application was already existing it had ODBC socket using,the file contents are 
 ID,Group \n
68247132,SK1202 \n
68247133,BURGER124 \n

Please try this, sorry it took wrongly while adding the question

Comment: Ah, okay. That is why I suggested code formatting the samples :) The regular formatting swallows the line breaks. Those values work fine too. ODBC returned "SK1202".

Comment: There could be slight differences in the file you are using. Any chance you could post a link to the actual file - or at least a sample that demonstrates the issue? Also, did you try using a schema.ini file?  BTW, if you have any choice about it, I would recommend inserting directly into the db instead. Most databases have better tools, many of which can be used from within cfquery, no extra processing needed.

Comment: I have set up with Schema.ini like this. http://codeceatures.blogspot.in/2015/03/odbc-driver-creation-and-csv-import.html .But When column having String Starting with 'SK' it gives problem and converts it to decimal value.